# Working on creating a rankings formula in Excel that is based on a range

Tags: excel, excel-2010

I have a spreadsheet I made and I have it set to rank 9 stores from 1-9. For example:

```
24-#5  
-1-#8  
18-#6
40-#4
81-#1
65-#3
16-#7
73-#2
```

What I want is a formula that still ranks, but I want a specific range to be ranked ahead of anyone who is more than 25, but negative still being the worst. For the numbers above it would look like this:

```
24-#1
-1-#8
18-#2
40-#4
81-#7
65-#5
16-#3
73-#6
```

Do you know how I can do this?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming data in `A2:A9` then you can avoid helper columns by using this formula in B2 copied down

`=IF(A2<0,RANK(A2,A$2:A$9),IF(A2<=25,COUNTIFS(A$2:A$9,"<=25",A$2:A$9,">"&A2)+1,COUNTIFS(A$2:A$9,">=0",A$2:A$9,"<"&A2)+1))`

Comment: +1 Was thinking for the longest while on how to do this without the helper column but couldn't get there :)

Answer (score 1):

The only way I can think of getting this to work is by manipulating the values before doing the ranking.

in a hidden column you can add the following formula

```
A    B
24   =IF(A1<0,A1*-MAX($A$1:$A$8),ABS(A1-25))
-1
18
40
-5
65
16
73
```

This gives you the following values

```
A       B
24     1
-1     81
18     7
40     15
81     56
65     40
16     9
73     48
```

This will give you new values that will rank in column C in the same order as desired (i.e. you can hide column B and the values returned from the `RANK` will align to your original values in column A)

```
A       B    C
24     1    =RANK(B1,$B$1:$B$8,1)
-1     81
18     7
40     15
81     56
65     40
16     9
73     48
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

[image]

In cell `G2` enter and copy down:

`=IF(AND(D2>=$B$1,D2<=$B$2),MAX($D$2:$D$9)+D2,IF(D2<0,-MAX($D$2:$D$9)+D2,-D2))`

In cell `H2` enter and copy down:

`=RANK.AVG(G2,$G$2:$G$9)`

The idea is to update your numbers based on `MIN`, `MAX`, and `special range` of your data, then use rank. You can put above 2 formulas together, if single cell solution is required.